# How can I simulate clicks for a mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, mobile

I am creating a web app. I was testing it on a mobile browser and noticed that `:active` pseudo class doesn't really work. How should I simulate clicks for a mobile browser? I'm specifically interested for Android and iPhone.

I am using css sprites. I stumbled upon `ontouchstart` but don't know how to use that. Can anyone help me over it?

Comment: just a thought, you're already using jQuery, have you looked at [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an answer for your question on SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940429/how-to-simulate-active-css-pseudo-class-in-android-on-non-link-elements

Even though the most upvoted answer has not been selected as THE answer by the poster, it seems to me that it is a valid solution for your problem. Also, the author indicates that the solution works on Iphone and Android.